# ASP .NET API Ajax How to update only some properties?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have a datatable and for each row there's a button. When clicked, it should set a property (field AvailableToCall) in my class. So I call an Ajax for my update method API passing the value (true) for the property. The problem is that when I do that, all the other properties (for example, name, adress, etc.) are set to null. Is there a way that I can update only a specific property leaving all the other properties of my table the same as before the AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/person/" + personId,
    type: "put",
    data: {
        AvailableToCall: true
    }
}).done(function () {
    // something
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have not shown your controller method! (you get the object from the db based on the `personId` and update its `AvailableToCall` property, then save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you could achieve this is a different endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/person/" + personId + "/availabletocall",
    type: "put",
    data: true
}).done(function () {
    // something
}
```

So your url is something like below which accepts a body with a boolean:

`/api/person/123/availabletocall`

Your controller action could simply receive that single value and update whichever datasource you're using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to show your ApiController method.

I assume your method is like this,

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
 {
  var _AvailableToCall = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["AvailableToCall"];
  //I'm using HttpContext to fetch the data in the above line. You can fetch  
  //the bool value as your way
  //Now you just need to fetch the data by personId, (here it is id).
  myClass obj = contextObj.myClass().where(m=>m.personId == 
                id).firstOrDefault();
  obj.AvailableToCall = true;
  //That's it. Now you can update it.
  contextObj.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  contextObj.SaveChanges();
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "OK", 
         Message = e.ToString() });
  //You can return your data as your requirements or as you are writing in 
  //your project.
  }
```

See here "contextObj" is the object of my Context Class. And "myClass" is my modal class that I want to update/save data.

You can write "Json" return type in place of "HttpResponseMessage". 
Cheers...